# Cauchy Schwarz inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $f_1,f_2$ be two functions on $L^2(\mathbb R^2/(2\pi \mathbb Z^2))$ that depend analytically on a parameter $t$.

Is the following expression then always positive?

$$G(f_1,f_2)(t) = \Vert \dot{f}_1 \Vert^2_2 \Vert f_2 \Vert^2_2 + \Vert \dot{f}_2 \Vert^2_2 \Vert f_1 \Vert^2_2 + 2 \Re((f_1,\dot{f}_1) (\dot{f}_2,f_1) -(\dot{f}_2,\dot{f}_1) (f_1,f_2))  -\vert (\dot{f}_1,f_2) \vert^2 - \vert(f_1,\dot{f}_2)\vert^2?$$

where $\dot{f}(t)=f'(t).$

It is clear that $$\Vert \dot{f}_1 \Vert^2_2 \Vert f_2 \Vert^2_2 + \Vert \dot{f}_2 \Vert^2_2 \Vert f_1 \Vert^2_2 \ge \vert (\dot{f}_1,f_2) \vert^2 +\vert(f_1,\dot{f}_2)\vert^2$$

by the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, but it is unclear to me what the situation is for the full expression.

Comment: The expression isn't even always real if $(f_1,f_2)$ has a non-zero imaginary part, due to $-(\dot{f}_2,\dot{f}_1) (f_1,f_2) - (\dot{f}_1,\dot{f}_2) (f_1,f_2)$ being equal to $-2\Re((\dot{f}_1,\dot{f}_2)) (f_1,f_2)$ and the rest being real. However, perhaps it's because of typos in the definition of $G$? $f_1$ and $f_2$ seem to have slightly asymmetrical roles due to the "$\Re((f_1,\dot{f}_1) (\dot{f}_2,f_1))$" part, and what I said previously can be fixed if either of the $(f_1, f_2)$s is swapped with $(f_2, f_1)$. (Also, $G$ here does not seem to be a function of $t$...?)

Comment: @BrunoB indeed, I accidentally swapped one inner product. G is indeed a function of $t$ as $f(t,x)$ is a function of $x \in \mathbb R^2/(2\pi \mathbb Z^2)$ and $t \in \mathbb C$

Comment: Is $(f,g) = \int f\bar g$ the Hermitian inner product? Usually round parentheses as in $(f,g) = \int fg$ is used for the real inner product while the angled braces $\langle f,g\rangle = \int f\bar g$ are used for the Hermitian inner product.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz it is the Hermitian inner product